# React Native: How to copy the error message on the simulator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7gIg.png)

Is such that:

When I run `react-native`,

There is an error message on the simulator.

I want to copy the error message and take Google.

But I can't copy it. Is there any suitable method?

Comment: HI..
if you not able to copy error message then you can set debugger .  there you will get the same error as mobile .  you can copy  that error
Open this URL :

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24524

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy error through Google Chrome Debugging.

You can enable debugging like this.

In react native app,Press `cmd + d` for iOS and `ctrl + R` for android.

**Select Option Show Debugging or Show Debug**

It will open Google chrome window for you.       Right click on it and open `inspect`

Now,

> in console tab   ,you can copy error in your app

Answer (score 0):

Use Android studio console it is better than Google Chrome debugging.

Answer (score -1):

Create consol.log('error')

When ever your code in error part then create log

Comment: consol or console?